# C# - Dynamically creating and moving picturebox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Okay so I'm trying to attempt to move a button around on a form. I use the following codes to call the button:

```
i++;
Button button = new Button();
button.Location = new Point(160, 30 * i + 10);
button.Click += new EventHandler(b_Click);
button.Tag = i;
panel1.Controls.Add(button);
```

I'm able to click each button and get a Messagebox showing their tag but I want to use their tag as a way to move the buttons around with a timer.

Comment: If this is in a loop (which I assume it is by the way it looks), you're creating new buttons all the time ... instead of moving your button ...

Comment: Your button's tag are the integer you assigned from the loop - what criteria is it for knowing which one to move?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is WinForms, you can use a Linq query on the Form Controls collection to find a button by its tag.

```
    var found = (from Control c 
                 in this.Controls 
                 where c.Tag == "ButtonTag"
                 select c).FirstOrDefault() as Button;

    if (found != null)
    {
        // manipulate the button
    }
```

I should note that this will only find top level controls on the form.  It would not find buttons that are inside of a container control (like a panel).  If your buttons are in a container, just replace "this" with the name of your container.

```
    var found = (from Control c 
                 in panel1.Controls 
                 where c.Tag == "ButtonTag"
                 select c).FirstOrDefault() as Button;
```

I should also note that this could be slow on a form with a large number of controls.